# Pass full slice range as parameter

Tags: go

Considering the code below, I have seen some code using this format `v[:]` for pass full slice (not part of it) as parameter.

Is there any difference between `v[:]` and  `v`? Or it is just a developer preference?

The test I did below show me no difference. Am I missing something?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    v := []byte {1, 2, 3}

    printSliceInfo(v)
    printSliceInfo(v[:])
}

func printSliceInfo(s []byte) {
    fmt.Printf("Len: %v - Cap: %v - %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When `v` is a slice, there is no difference between `v` and `v[:]`. When `v` is an array, `v[:]` is a slice covering the entirety of the array.

Comment: I guess so... I've never seen a case of passing a slice by `v[:]` in the wild, and I don't know why anyone would do it that way - it's unnecessary and potentially just confusing.

Comment: Here is just one place where I see it. In this pkg 3 examples use slice in this way. https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/rsa/#example_VerifyPKCS1v15

Comment: Not so: `sha256.Sum()` returns an array, `hashed[:]` is used there to convert the array to a slice.

Answer (score -1):

There is a difference. You may want to read [Slice Expression in the Golang spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions)

```
a[:]   // same as a[0 : len(a)]
```

`v[:]` is actually a **new** slice value (that is you then have two slices - v & v[:]), so you need to think why you really need it before doing this. Here's something which may help you understand the difference maybe after you read up a bit on slices: https://play.golang.org/p/cJgfYGS78H

p.s.: What you have defined above `v := []byte {1, 2, 3}` is a slice, so array is not in picture here.

Comment: Passing `v` *also creates a new slice value*. In both cases, you pass a copy of the slice, which in both cases references the same underlying array. There is no practical difference between the two approaches.

Comment: You are mistaken @adrian I never said that passing v doesn't create a value, so I don't know where you picked this up from -  passing to a function always passes by value in Go and creates a copy. However, if you do a v[:], **you are creating an additional (possibly redundant) copy of the slice** - please investigate it, if you aren't sure. I'm not talking about passing it to a function at all. Maybe I shouldn't have included the function example at all! So mentioning that "When v is a slice, there is no difference between v and v[:]" is wrong - kindly correct it.

Comment: Regardless of whether you're passing it to a function or assigning it to another variable, it creates a copy *either way*. I'm not correcting it because it is correct - *there is no difference* when `v` is a slice.

Comment: #1 When v is already there, doing a v[:], makes no sense, it just creates another (redundant) value.

Comment: If the value wouldn't be used, it would either be eliminated by the compiler, or it wouldn't compile at all. If the value would be used, both `v` and `v[:]` create a copy.

Comment: The point is `v[:]` creates a new slice value for an existing slice `v` - so `v` and `v[:]` are not the same. And v[:] may not be needed. Once this is clear, one can do what is needed.  I am not talking about passing it to a function, A copy is not in picture here. Yes, but if `v[:]` is passed to a function, it'll create yet another copy of `v`. These comments are being added so that a reader is not mislead.